# How can I call a method like Console.WriteLine in a CodeStatement of a CodeConditionStatement?

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I can't figure out how to call and use method in a if statement through CodeDOM. Does somebody have already done something similar?

Actually, the parameters that represents the "true statement" (in the CodeConditionStatement) requires 'statement' parameters, but the only way I know to call a method is CodeMethodInvokeExpression which is an 'expression' and not a 'statement' so it gives me an error for this.

```
CodeConditionStatement ifPath = new CodeConditionStatement(
                // condition: System.IO.Path.Exit(path)
                new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(method.Parameters[1].Name), "Path.Exist", new CodeExpression[] { new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("path") }),
                // true:
                new CodeStatement[] {
                    new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(method.Parameters[0].Name), "Console.WriteLine", new CodeExpression[] { new CodePrimitiveExpression("Saisir mot de passe") })
                },
                // false:
                new CodeStatement[] { new CodeCommentStatement("Else block. If condition is false, execute these statements.") }
            );
```

Currently, it just gives an error advertise saying "unable to convert implicitly the type 'System.CodeDom.CodeMethodInvokeExpression' in 'System.CodeDom.CodeStatement'".

Comment: I guess you want to use CodeExpressionStatement instead of CodeMethodInvokeExpression...

Comment: How yeah! It just solves my problem. Thank you. I am kinda new to all of this.